# Send certain value to the next activity according to radio buttons

Tags: java, android-studio

The problem that I have faced:
The Female radiobutton checked can show the result in another activity successfully, but the Male radiobutton checked cannot show the result in another activity.

MainActivity17.java

```
public class MainActivity17 extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioButton male, female;
    Double maleAmount;
    Double femaleAmount;
    String textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main17);

    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(final View view) {
        final boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        final EditText editTextUser = findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        final TextView textViewOutput = findViewById(R.id.textViewOutput);


        male = findViewById(R.id.ButtonMale);
        female = findViewById(R.id.ButtonFemale);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                final Double userInput = Double.parseDouble(editTextUser.getText().toString());

                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.ButtonMale:
                        if (checked)
                            maleAmount = (userInput * 40);
                        textViewOutput.setText(nm.format(maleAmount));

                        break;

                    case R.id.ButtonFemale:
                        if (checked)
                            femaleAmount = (userInput * 40 * 2);
                        textViewOutput.setText(nm.format(femaleAmount));
                        break;
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity17.this, MainActivity18.class);
                textview = textViewOutput.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("String", textview);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

main_activity17.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity17">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="Enter Amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ButtonMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ButtonFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:text="Next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOutput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity18.java - I want to show the result in this activity

```
public class MainActivity18 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String valFromAct1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main18);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        valFromAct1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("String");
        textView.setText(valFromAct1);
    }
}
```

main_activity18.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity18">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:text="this is activity 2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need some modification in the first activity.
you should not bind your views in the onclick method and it is not a good idea to add set the onClick method in the onRadioButton Click. instead, use disable attribute of the button.

**MainActivity17.java**

```
public class MainActivity17 extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioButton male, female;
    Double maleAmount;
    Double femaleAmount;
    String textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main17);
        final EditText editTextUser = findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        final TextView textViewOutput = findViewById(R.id.textViewOutput); 
        male = findViewById(R.id.ButtonMale);
        female = findViewById(R.id.ButtonFemale); 
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                final Double userInput = Double.parseDouble(editTextUser.getText().toString());

                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.ButtonMale:
                        if (checked)
                            maleAmount = (userInput * 40);
                        textViewOutput.setText(nm.format(maleAmount));

                        break;

                    case R.id.ButtonFemale:
                        if (checked)
                            femaleAmount = (userInput * 40 * 2);
                        textViewOutput.setText(nm.format(femaleAmount));
                        break;
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity17.this, MainActivity18.class);
                textview = textViewOutput.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("String", textview);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(final View view) {
        final boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    }
}
```

**But** if you want to use multiple radio buttons you can use the below method for notifying the selected item:

```
// Add the Listener to the RadioGroup 
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( 
        new RadioGroup 
            .OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
                @Override

                // The flow will come here when 
                // any of the radio buttons in the radioGroup 
                // has been clicked 

                // Check which radio button has been clicked 
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, 
                                             int checkedId) 
                { 

                    // Get the selected Radio Button 
                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.ButtonMale:
                            maleAmount = (userInput * 40);
                        textViewOutput.setText(nm.format(maleAmount));

                        break;

                    case R.id.ButtonFemale:
                            femaleAmount = (userInput * 40 * 2);
                        textViewOutput.setText(nm.format(femaleAmount));
                        break;
                }
                } 
            });
```